# No Azure subscription found for this tree item

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy my code from local to Azure
Not sure why for the first time the deploy function is working perfectly, but it keeps prompting "No Azure subscription found for this tree item."
[image: Deploy to container]

[image: No Azure subscription found for this tree item.]

-not using poxy

-tried Signing-out and signing-in Azure

I am trying to deploy my code from local to Azure

Expecting the code to deploy on Azure portal

Comment: check if any resource policy or resource group is preventing the deployment action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I created function app in Azure portal.

[image]

- I created sample node.js application in my Local by using required commands in in my terminal.
- I am also getting same error while doing the process mentioned in above image.

[image]

- I have tried another approach to deploy the node app to function app to check below.

[image]

- By using the above approach deployed successfully.

[image]

- To check the deployment status in azure portal.

[image]

Comment: I used to also deploy from the "Local Project" but now you have to do it from the "Remote Project", This makes little sense but it works.